# sed move pattern to beginning of line

Tags: sed

I have a textfile with lines of text where I want to move a pattern to the beginning of the line with sed.  The pattern is the sequences like `[35 of 44]`.

```
CSV files and Jupyter _ Even More Python for Beginners - Data Tools [35 of 44].description
Calling An API _ Python for Beginners [36 of 44].description
```

With **`\\[.*?\\]`** I can match this part `[11 of 31]` of the line, but I can't figure out how to move this pattern to the start of the line.

```
[35 of 44] CSV files and Jupyter _ Even More Python for Beginners - Data Tools.description
[36 of 44] Calling An API _ Python for Beginners.description
```

Hopefully, someone can help me!

Comment: Note that `sed` doesn't support non-greedy, so `.*?` doesn't work.  See also: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905/109046)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following.

```
awk '
match($0,/\[[^]]*\]/){
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),substr($0,1,RSTART-1) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using `match` function of `awk` to match from `[` to till `]` in each line then printing the matched text's sub string first followed by rest of the line's value.

Answer (score 4):

You need to capture both what matches and what precedes it to do the replacement.  In `sed`, the `\(…\)` captures what's in the `…` part.  Hence:

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\)\(\[[^]]*\]\)/\2\1/'
```

Using single quotes on the command line avoids needing to use doubled-up backslashes.

As shown, this generates:

```
[35 of 44]CSV files and Jupyter _ Even More Python for Beginners - Data Tools .description
[36 of 44]Calling An API _ Python for Beginners .description
```

If you want a space after the `[n of m]` information, add it:

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\)\(\[[^]]*\]\)/\2 \1/'
```

Note that if there are two or more `[n of m]` sequences on the line, only the last one will be moved.  Also, the search does not enforce that the material between the square brackets is of the form `[1 of 2]` (number of number).  It would be possible to do so; it is not clear that it is worth worrying about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following POSIX ERE based `sed` command:

```sh
sed -E 's/(.*[^[:space:]])[[:space:]]*(\[[0-9]+ of [0-9]+])/\2 \1/' file
```

*Details*:

- `-E` - enables POSIX ERE  syntax (less escaping)
- `(.*[^[:space:]])` - Group 1: any text and then a non-whitespace char
- `[[:space:]]*` - zero or more whitespace
- `(\[[0-9]+ of [0-9]+])` - Group 2: `[`, one or more digits, space, `of`, space, one or more digits, `]`.

The replacement is `\2 \1`, that is, Group 1 value, space, Group 2 value.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/1wTTMt):

```sh
s='CSV files and Jupyter _ Even More Python for Beginners - Data Tools [35 of 44].description
Calling An API _ Python for Beginners [36 of 44].description'
sed -E 's/(.*[^[:space:]])[[:space:]]*(\[[0-9]+ of [0-9]+])/\2 \1/' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
[35 of 44] CSV files and Jupyter _ Even More Python for Beginners - Data Tools.description
[36 of 44] Calling An API _ Python for Beginners.description
```